# Comparing two columns from different files using R

Tags: r, matching

I need help in matching two documents, between two columns so that it picks the pair in document 1, and loops through docuemnt 2 finding matches and outputs the match with the least difference (best possible match). For example looking at the data below,I would like the output in to be in document 2, where it shows the matching values from document 2
Document 1
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 0.12   | 23.45   |
| 0.13   | 25.65  |

Document 2
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 0.12   | 23.45   |
| 0.12   | 23.46   |

Output

| Column A | Column B | match from doc2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | 0.12 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |  |

I developed the following script to do that.

```
r1
r2
matched_hold = list()
# Loop through rows in r1
for (row in r1$rowid) {
 zval = r1$RTB[r1$rowid == row]
 mval = r1$MZB[r1$rowid == row]
 # Check if zval and mval are numeric
 if (is.numeric(zval) && is.numeric(mval)) {
  r2_copy = r2 %>%
   filter((RTA < zval + 0.05 & RTA > zval - 0.05) &
        (MZA < mval + 0.01 & MZA > mval - 0.01))
  r2_copy$RTB = zval
  r2_copy$MZB = mval
  matched_hold[[row]] = r2_copy
 }
}
# Combine the matched data frames
matched_df = do.call('rbind', matched_hold)
```

However, the script is faulty in that it does not bring the best possible match, for example if there are two matches one with a difference of 0.5 and another with a difference of 0.1, instead of picking the 0.1 it would pick the 0.5 match. Could you help me modify it so that the result returns the best possible match base don the criteria provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I must admit I am confused with the example you put, let me rephrase it and make something more simple so we can understand easily each other. I'll help you through it using your "looping" method too. Feel free to change it to satisfy your specific needs

Here we have our two dataframes that we want to compare:

```
df1 = data.frame(RTA=c(1, 2.1, 0, NA), MZA=c(4, 5.1, 0, NA))
df2 = data.frame(RTB=c(1, 2, 3, NA), MZB=c(4, 5, 6, NA))
```

Now let's do the looping method you tried, but making some little changes

```
# You don't need to use an ID column for the loop, can be risky
matched_hold = list()
for (row_df1 in 1:nrow(df1)){
  
  # Let's select the row values
  rta_val = df1$RTA[row_df1]
  mza_val = df1$MZA[row_df1]
  
  # As you wanted, we only consider cases when both values are numeric (and not NA values!)
  if (is.numeric(rta_val) & is.numeric(mza_val) & !is.na(rta_val+mza_val)){
    
    # Instead of a nested loop we use a vectorial composition to get all differences values
    diff_per_row = abs(df2$RTB - rta_val) + abs(df2$MZB - mza_val) # Differences should be absolute!
    
    # Now, what is the cell most similar to this cell? You can find out
    row_df2 = which.min(diff_per_row)
    
    # Introduce that cell as the list value
    matched_hold[[row_df1]] = row_df2
     
  }
}
```